# error in adding two pointer in getting http request program

Tags: c++

I have a code that will read the url inside of a txt file and will get http request.

Here's the url inside of the txt file

www.stackoverflow.com

Here's the initial code:

```
int main()
{
//getting the data
HANDLE openFile;
BOOL rewriFile;
char *strVal;
DWORD dwNoBytetoRead = 0;

//connecting to the server
SOCKET Socket;
SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
struct hostent *host;
int dataLen;
int i = 0;
//get
const char* httpRequestget = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.stackoverflow.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
//winsock startup
WSAData wsaData;

//start of program.................................

//open file
openFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\url.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

//allocating memory
LARGE_INTEGER fs;
GetFileSizeEx(openFile, &fs);
unsigned long long fSize = fs.QuadPart;
strVal = new char[fSize + 1];
memset(strVal, 0, fSize + 1);

//reading the content
rewriFile = ReadFile(openFile, strVal, fSize, &dwNoBytetoRead, NULL);
cout << "The URL is " << strVal << endl << endl;

CloseHandle(openFile);

//split string
point = strtok(strVal, ",\r\n");
while (point != NULL) {

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
    cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
    system("pause");
    //return 1;
}

//connects to domain
Socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
host = gethostbyname(point);

SockAddr.sin_port=htons(80);
SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

  if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
    cout << "Could not connect";
    system("pause");
    //return 1;
  }else{
      cout << "You are now connected to " << point << endl;
  }
// Sending a HTTP-GET-Request to the Web Server
int sentBytes = send(Socket, httpRequestget, strlen(httpRequestget),0);
```

My concern is on this part -> const char* httpRequestget = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.stackoverflow.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"; when the url is hard coded in a request, the code is working but

When I change the url to variable "strVal" (which is where the read URL was stored)-> **const char* httpRequestget = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + strVal + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";** it shows an error that two pointers cannot be added.

NOTE: when I change const char* httpRequestGet = to std:string httpRequestGet = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + strVal + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"; it will have an error **error C2664: 'send' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::string' to 'const char *** and **still an error that two pointers cannot be added.**

Is there a way I can solve this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make `httpRequestget` a `std::string`.

Comment: hi @JesperJuhl I tried to make it a string (std::string httpRequestget = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + strVal +"\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";) but still it has an error -> error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers

Comment: Make *all* of your strings `std::string`.  That is the easiest solution.  Your `strVal` is a pointer, `"\r\nConnection..."\` is *not* a string, it is also a pointer -- make those `std::string`.